# Git: ignore a file from a subtree, but track it locally and push it to a remote production

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, git-subtree

I have a quite specific workflow and the reason for that is that I use `git subtree` to include one project inside another:

- a local git repository `styling` which is updated by `pull` from a remote repository (`styling-exchange`);
- another local repository `styling-bare` which is used to sync `styling` and `code`
- another local git repository `code` which has the `code/styling` subdirectory added as a [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) via a remote branch called `styling` (`../styling-bare`)
- a remote `production` repository which can be updated from `code` with `git push production master`

It should look like this:

```
code
|--/.git
|--.gitignore
|--/styling
|  |--file1
|  |--file2.v1
|--file3
styling-bare
styling
|--/.git
|--.gitignore
|--file1
|--file2.v2
```

There are two use cases for the workflow:

1. `cd` into `styling`, pull from `styling-exchange`, then `cd` into `code`, update the `styling` subtree, do some changes to `file1` and `file2` and `file3`, push to `production`
2. `cd` into `code`, do some changes to `file1` and `file2` and `file3`, push changes to `styling-bare` (subtree push), `cd` into `styling`, pull from `styling-bare`, push changes to `styling-exchange`

I would like to have two completely different and separate versions of `file2` in the local repositories `styling/styling-bare` VS the `code/production` repositories. I need to get all updates from the `styling` subtree into `code/styling`, but I need to track `file2` just inside `code`, without any updates from `styling`.

I.e. I would like to update the `styling` subtree in the `code` repository, but keep my own version of `file2` when I do that (while having `file1` synced between `styling` and `code` and file3 synced between `code` and `production`), so that I can push my own version (v1) of `file2` to `production` later.

**Is there any elegant way to do that in git without symlinks or some sophisticated hooks?**

*Note, I have experimented with:*

- .gitignore `file2` in the `code` repository: this does not work, the file is there once I do subtree pull to the `styling` subtree;
- [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100933/how-to-ignore-files-and-folders-with-pull-requests-to-github-in-distinct-git-clo) .gitignore [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456533/is-there-a-way-to-setup-remote-specific-gitignores) for different branches, but this breaks once I do merge;
- I have tried to [exclude](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches) `file2` with .git/info/exclude_from_styling, this has no effect;
- I have tried to remove `file2` from index with `git update-index --assume-unchanged styling/file2`, but this does not solve my problem;
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147827/track-files-in-local-git-repo-but-ignore-in-remote) solution will not work for me, because I will not be able to push all the `styling` directory to `production`;
- I am not sure that a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767854/track-local-ignored-files-with-git) could help to solve the problem;
- I need to keep the same name for `file2` in all the repositories, so the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031800/how-to-keep-different-content-of-one-file-in-my-local-and-github-repository/6031981#6031981) with different names is not helpful either.

Comment: That reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/17162624/6309, but this isn't an exact answer for you (and you already are using subtree)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions that come to mind :

- Instead of a plain `git subtree pull`, you can use a script to pull the changes in your `code` repository, which would do something along the lines :

  `git subtree pull ... && git checkout branch/with/my/specific/file2 -- styling/file2.v1`
- You can pull the changes from `styling` in a special branch used only for pulling, and merge the changes into your own branch. I haven't tested it, but there should be ways to systematically say "keep my version of this file on merge" : [tell git to use ours merge strategy on specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files)

I woudln't exactly call this elegant, and each method has its flaws.

You mentioned you wanted to avoid hooks, but you could also put the `git checkout branch/with/my/specific/file2 -- styling/file2.v1` in a post-commit hook, or in a "smudger" on checkout (I just found out about [git filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion))

Answer (score 0):

1. If one is generated *like a minification*, you may consider having a script that automatically builds it. As a rule of thumb: Never, but never put generated code in a VCS.
2. If v1 is the same file though as v2, use

   ```
   git diff <sha>..<sha>
   ```

   or you may even use a GUI (e.g. meld):

   ```
   git difftool <sha>..<sha>
   ```
3. If you do not make changes to both of them, do not add the same project twice in your subtree, but use a script to get it any time you need it (the read-only version of it).

It would help to know the languages, frameworks you're using this project layout.